# Action Bar cut with SlidingMenu and Overlay of ActionBar Sherlock

Tags: android, overlay, actionbarsherlock

I'm working with the ActionBarSherlock library and the Sliding Menu library for a Black Ops 2 guide application and've tryed to insert the beatiful "Overlay" function in the same activity of the Sliding Menu.
The result is:

- The overlay doesn't work
- Action bar cut

This is the code:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.c_m_pyrrhicvictory);   
    Resources res = getResources();
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.main_slidingmenu);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().
         getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_bg_black));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("1/10 Standard");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Missions");
```

Screenshots:
[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BANZD.png)
[SlidingMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRz03.png)

Comment: I am encountering the same pb. It seems that this is a limitation of SlidingMenu. Going through the code of this library & actionbarsherlock might help, if not it might be a good idea to open a ticket in the github repo of sliding menu.

Comment: Is there Different library for Both ActionBar & Sliding Menu??

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.
In file SlidingMenu.java find the function

```
public void attachToActivity(Activity activity, int slideStyle) {
        attachToActivity(activity, slideStyle, false);
    }
```

and change third parameter to true,
attachToActivity(activity, slideStyle, true);
i.e actionbarOverlay param should be set to **true**.
It works for me.
Don't forget to add topMargin or padding into the Menu layout, because the first list item may be hidden by ActionBar. See onLayout function in CustomViewBehind.java.